# Checking if an address is a multiple of 8 with bitwise operation in assembly SPARC

Tags: bitwise-operators, sparc

How do I check if an address is a multiple of 8 with bitwise operation in assembly Sparc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well in C you would need to do something like this:

```
is_multiple_of_8 = (addr & (8 - 1)) == 0;
```

So just convert this to asm, either by hand or by getting the compiler to help you (e.g. `gcc -S`). It should really only be 2 or 3 instructions at most: you just need to AND the address with 7, then test for zero.